# use excel or powershell to turn a long list of numbers into groups of ranges where a range exists

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-formula

I have around 187,000 10 digit numbers. Many of them are in sequence like:

```
1112223333
1112223334
1112223335
```

etc.

but there are holes, a lot of them.

How can i group these up so instead of this:

```
1112223332
1112223334
1112223335
1112223336
1112223337
1112223338
1112223339
1112223340
1112223341
1112223342
1112223344
1112223345
1112223346
1112223347
1112223349
1113334444
1113334445
1113335555
1114445555
```

i get:

```
1112223332
1112223334-1112223342
1112223344-1112223347
1112223349
1113334444-1113334445
1113335555
1114445555
```

i know i can use excel to do an IF function that checks the value of a cell to see if it's 1 greater then the value above it. This will FLAG where holes exist, but putting that out to 187000 records will still end up as a dramatic amount of manual work.

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(n,A1:A19,
     a,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(IF(ISNA(XMATCH(n+{-1,1},n)),n,NA()),2),2),
     t,TAKE(a,,1),
     d,DROP(a,,1),
IF(t=d,t,t&-d))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}}),

//Add offset column to check if 
// difference = 1 or not
    #"Offset Cols" =Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") 
        & {List.RemoveFirstN(#"Changed Type"[Column1]) & {null}},
        type table[Col1=Int64.Type, OffsetUp=Int64.Type]),

//Add index column, then create Grouping column depending on difference between successive rows
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Offset Cols", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Grouper", 
        each if [Col1] + 1=[OffsetUp] then null else [Index], Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"OffsetUp", "Index"}),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Removed Columns",{"Grouper"}),

//Group, then extract the items
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Up", {"Grouper"}, {
            {"Sequence", each 
                if Table.RowCount(_)=1 then Text.From([Col1]{0}) 
                else Text.From([Col1]{0}) & " - " & Text.From(List.Last([Col1])), type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Grouper"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should at least attempt to solve the problem by yourself before asking here but this is a fun exercise so, here is how you can do it in
[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell). This is hardcoding all given numbers, I would assume you have these numbers in a file and if so you should research how to read the content from a file.

```bash
$numbers = @'
1112223332
1112223334
1112223335
1112223336
1112223337
1112223338
1112223339
1112223340
1112223341
1112223342
1112223344
1112223345
1112223346
1112223347
1112223349
1113334444
1113334445
1113335555
1114445555
'@ -split '\r?\n'

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numbers.Count; $i++) {
    # current item
    $current = $numbers[$i]
    # next item
    $next = $numbers[$i + 1]

    # if current item + 1 is not equal to the next item
    if (1 + $current -ne $next) {
        # if i'm not holding a value in this variable
        if (-not $start) {
            # output it
            $current
            # and go next
            continue
        }

        # else, (I do have a value in `$start`), output a formatted string
        # representing the `$start` followed by a hyphen `-` followed by the current number
        '{0}-{1}' -f $start, $current
        # reset the `$start` variable
        $start = $null
        # and go next
        continue
    }

    # if current item + 1 is equal to the next item
    if (-not $start) {
        # store the current number in this variable
        $start = $current
    }
}
```

This would output:

```
1112223332
1112223334-1112223342
1112223344-1112223347
1112223349
1113334444-1113334445
1113335555
1114445555
```